# Collisions are not being detected correctly

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision-detection

I'm having trouble with collision detection in Unity.
Specifically, when the collision is clearly entered, the `OnCollisionEnter` method doesn't get called, and magically it only be called when I do some action in `Unity Editor`, for example, navigating from the `Game` tab to the `Scene` tab. I know it sounds magic, so I recorded a video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CtWB3cMcUyk).
This issue doesn't appear if I set the `Collision Detection` property in `Rigidbody` component of the Robot to `Continuous Speculative`, but as you can see, that robot's velocity is super slow and I have no reason to choose the most expensive option.

Is there any other way to solve it?
Thanks.

Comment: Why do you have both OnTriggerEnter and OnCollisionEnter? in your video the OnTriggerEnter seems to be called according to the log, also this seems to be working, could you provide a demo of when it's not working?

Comment: The OnCollisionEnter and OnTriggerEnter is working fine in most cases. Also my game having bunch of triggers to control gameplay, that's why OnTriggerEnter get called, then I cleared them. The problem only appear when it collide with the block I shown in the video. That's the magic point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the reason, it was because I made the `Character Controller` component overlap the `Sphere Collider` component. And somehow, the collision between Block and my character is always detected by the `Character Controller` instead of `Sphere Collider`. So the solution is to make the `Sphere Collider` little bit bigger than `Character Controller`

[image]